# Why is Flexslider not initialised?

Tags: html, css, slider, flexslider

http://ashwin931996.webege.com/

The Flexslider is not initialised. Any reason why?

The css and js are linked correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery should be loaded first, so do it on `document.ready`

```
   $(function(){
      SyntaxHighlighter.all();
      $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        start: function(slider){
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: `SyntaxHighlighter.all();` - not defined! correct this error or just comment this line and it will work.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
  });
</script> `

This is the code from the official Flexslider website.
http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/.
I have used the code given by flexslider itself, It ain't working still.

Comment: too many errors :) `<script src="js/jquery.flexslider"></script>` - should be `<script src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>`

Comment: what does `SyntaxHighlighter.all();` does? @Reflective